# Покупать ещё и рис было, по-честному, **необязательно**

Tags: орфография

Можно писать *необязательно, необязательный* вместо *не обязательно, не обязательный*, коль имеется в виду 'лишний, излишне'?

> Покупать ещё и рис было, по-честному, **необязательно**.

> Чечевица **необязательна** для Нового года.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В этой теме используются **три грамматические формы** (обычное наречие, предикативное наречие и краткое прилагательное), но все они выступают **в роли сказуемого.** В этом случае выбрать отрицание (не является обязательным) или утверждение (является излишним) **довольно сложно,** поэтому надо учитывать **контекст** и **лексику** конкретного предложения. Ведь остановиться нужно на **одном** варианте.

(1) *Покупать ещё и рис было, по-честному, **не обязательно**.*

Ситуация вполне **конкретная.** Купили рис, но он не так уж срочно был нужен, хотя потом пригодится. Как записать? Оценка автора есть (**по-честному**), слово с НЕ семантически выделено. Поэтому лучше выбрать **отрицание.**

(2) *Чечевица **необязательна** для Нового года.*

Это **общее** суждение, контекст не нужен. Чечевица обычно не используется для новогоднего стола, поэтому продукт можно назвать **лишним**. Выбираем слитное написание (утверждение противоположного признака).